# Django substring

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if there is a way to return a substring in django after retrieving a chunk of data from a column in the database. In this case, I'm trying to retrieve data from the 'contents' column to manipulate the text available and return it.

Retrieval of question list method

```
def prepare_questions(subject_id, scope, sort, topic, subtopic):
   question_list = Question.objects.filter(subject=subject_id)
return question_list
```

Model that contains contents

```
class Question(models.Model):
   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
   content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Content'))
```

What I hope to do is to take question_list's data from 'contents', pass it through a substring method in python. I'm unsure of the steps I should take from here. In addition I would like the method result to be returned as part of the question_list with a new key tagged to the method return value as I do not want to override the original 'contents' value retrieved.

Any pointers or references greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your description of what you hope to do is quite unclear. can you give an example of some input and output data?

Comment: Can you give more detail about what is stored in the Content column? What are you parsing in each entry of Content list? Sample data would be a great way to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a method on your model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def contents_substring(self):
        # do stuff
        return the_substring
```

Then any time you access an instance, whether on it's own or in a loop, you can just do:

```
instance.contents_substring()
```

Or in a template:

```
{{ instance.contents_substring }}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a better, simpler way to do it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
return [{'substring': substring_method(q.content), 'question': q} for q in question_list]
```

Naturally you'll have to define or replace `substring_method` with whatever Python substring method you want.

What this line does is uses Python's "list comprehension" syntax to map each `Question` object in `question_list` into a dictionary with two items, i.e. `substring` (the substring) and `question` (the original `Question` object).

Here's how you might use the new `prepare_questions`:

```
questions = prepare_questions( ... )  # whatever arguments
first_question = questions[0]  # let's assume there's at least 1
print first_question['substring']  # prints the substring of the first question's content
print first_question['question'].content  # prints the first question's full content
```

For completeness, here's a simple example 'substring_method':

```
def substring_method(s):
    return s[1:4]  # use Python slice syntax to return 2nd through 4th chars of string
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, it looks feasible but I used Chris Patt's solution :-)